# htaccess и 404, запрет редиректа

Tags: .htaccess

есть htaccess и в нем прописаны следующие строки:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Я залил файл в корень вида 12345.txt и пытаюсь его открыть, и мне выводит 404 страницу на сайте, как быть?

Comment: Было бы странно, если бы .htaccess'a не было )

Comment: Могу предположить, что файл 12345.txt Apache ищет в каталоге public и не находит, поэтому и 404. Но ваш вопрос в целом все равно не понятен. Что вы по итогу хотите запретить (что за редирект) и причем тут файл из корня?

Comment: @misdeed почему странно? mod_rewrite отлично работает в контексте директивы VirtualHost, например. А файл htaccess в тот же момент может быть запрещен.